# MYSQL Select all pilots that can fly all types of airplanes

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables on MYSQL.

**Table : Pilot**

```
columns: pilot_id, name, salary
```

**Table :  Certificate**

```
columns: pilot_id, type_of_plane
```

I need to select the name and salary of all pilots that can fly all types of planes. Can someone please help me?

Comment: any data example may can help us solve your problem

Comment: can you please provide the all table information and relations. I think you are missing here planes tables which having plane_type field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to doing this:

1. Ensure that you have a constraint in your DB for the Certificate
   column that ensures uniqueness of the pair pilot_id, type_of_plane
2. Issue one query to do a distinct count of type_of_plane.
3. Issue another query that counts how many type_of_plane's each pilot can fly (this is a simple group by with a count): 
   `SELECT COUNT(type_of_plane) FROM Certificate GROUP BY pilot_ID`
4. Then apply a filter to the above COUNT query that only returns the pilots that have a certain count - use the HAVING clause.
5. You can combine step 2 into step 4 by doing a subquery.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you'd posted sample data at least. But anyways:

Step 1- Count distinct type_of_plane from Certificate. =AllTypesOfPlane

Step 2- Select pilot_id , Count type_of_plane group by pilot_id where count(type_of_plane) = AllTypesOfPlane

Step3- The resultset could be empty too cause there can be no pilots who can fly all types of planes. but anywyas if its not, now use pilot_id to get the salary.

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given:

```
select distinct p.name 
from 
pilot p,certificates c 
where p.pilot_id=c.pilot_id 
group by p.pilot_id 
having 
(count(distinct c.type_of_plane)=(select count(distinct type_of_plane) from certificates));
```